# Joomla database memory leak

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

My client has got a pretty large Joomla-based website hosted on Amazon EC2 with 1.5GB of RAM. The server hosts both Apache and MySQL. Right now the database size is around 250MB and the website gets daily traffic of about 5000. It looks like there is a severe memory leak on the website as sometimes MySQL uses about 99% of CPU memory and then crashes. I have tried optimizing database tables, modifying my`.cnf`, but still there is no improvement.

There are finder tables used by Joomla smart search which occupy over 100MB of db size. I have disabled smart search, but still the problem occurs.

Friends, please throw some suggestions in fixing this.

Thanks.

Below is the my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

default-storage-engine=innodb
transaction-isolation    =   REPEATABLE-READ
character-set-server    =   UTF8
collation-server      =   UTF8_general_ci

max_connections         = 5000
wait_timeout            = 30
connect_timeout         = 60
#interactive_timeout     = 600
#max_connect_errors      = 1000000
#max_allowed_packet      = 10M


skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

slow_query_log
long_query_time = 2

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that mysql leaks. What I believe more - is that your application performs terrible queries.

Comment: Its a basic setup modifying an existing theme with no custom code. It uses about 25 regular joomla plugins. Everything just works fine on my localhost. The problem is occurring only on production. I will once again go through the code and see what might be the issue.

Comment: Slow query log shows...?

Comment: How about telling us what extensions, and turn on debug and put up the queries it generates.

Comment: Please post your my.cnf; It might help with diagnosing your problem.

Comment: Was this site migrated from 1.5? Most slow queries we see are due to corrupted asset tables from 1.5.

Comment: The slow query log shows that one of the queries in Jomla's K2 extension is taking a lot o time. About 75sec. But this extension is very important and core to the project. No it was not migrated from 1.5.

Comment: Same problem here, but with 1.5; which version are you running? Have you tried enabling debug to see how many database hits you get per page view?

Comment: Its Joomla 2.5.4. I am getting about 36 DB hits per page view. This one was on home page. On internal pages it is slightly less.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be that you are being hit by a rogue robot - one of the many SEO spiders out there, or tools like 80legs that let people program a network of bots to carry out tasks - often with errors in their programming that result in a heavy bombardment.

I can never remember which of the MySQL settings take memory once and which are per connection - but as you are set to allow up to 5000 simultaneous connections and some of the buffers are 2 and 8 MB I'd bet that the total memory usage under heavy load could easily be in excess of the total ram available.

Your current settings would allow all of your daily traffic to hit simultaneously. I'd knock that down to a setting of a hundred or less and see if that gives more stability.

There are various MySQL tuner scripts out there that can help you spot where too much memory is allocated.

If you have access logs from around the time of the crashes / high load I'd check for malicious bots though - we've had a constant battle to reign them in on some sites we monitor/control.

You might also check the thread_concurrency value - depending upon how many CPUs you have available.